# How I do read a file from end to start with C threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I need to read a file with 2 threads, one of them will read the file from beginning to middle and the other one will read the file from end to middle. I have 10 float numbers in my file. First 5 float will sum by one thread and last 5 float will sum by other. func1 is okay but I could not handle the func2 part.

```
float sum=0,sum1=0,sum2=0,flo;  
int i=0;
FILE *fp;

 void *func1(void *param) {
      for(i=1;i<=5;i++) {
      fscanf(fp,"%f",&flo);
      sum1=flo+sum1;
}
      pthread_exit(0);
}
int main() {

   pthread_t tid;   
   pthread_attr_t attr;   
   pthread_attr_init(&attr);

   fp = fopen("input.txt","r");
   pthread_create(&tid, &attr, func1,fp);
   pthread_create(&tid, &attr, func2,fp);
   pthread_join(tid, NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest technique is to use a single thread to do the reading.  However, given that this is an exercise in using POSIX threads, then:

- You should always check the return value from `fscanf()` — threads or no threads.
- You should eschew global variables even in unthreaded programs.
- With threads and `i`, `sum1` and `flo` all being global, you are setting yourself up for horrid race conditions.  You should have mutexes to prevent concurrent access to those variables.  Or, better, make them all local to the thread function.
- You would also need to make the functions return an appropriate value.
- You should use the parameter that's passed to the thread function.
- You should save the thread ID values in separate variables so you can wait for both threads to finish; your code only waits for one thread to finish (the second one).
- You should print the result.
- You don't have to worry about synchronization on the file stream — POSIX requires that to happen anyway (see [`flockfile()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/flockfile.html) and its close relatives all documented on the same page).
- You should provide both `func1()` and `func2()` to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  I'm assuming that the same function will do for both threads, which isn't a risky assumption in context.

Putting that together leads to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct tcb
{
    FILE *fp;
    double sum;
    int thread_num;
};

static void *func1(void *param)
{
    struct tcb *tcb = param;
    double sum1 = 0.0, flo;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        if (fscanf(tcb->fp, "%lf", &flo) != 1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Thread %d failed to read value %d\n", tcb->thread_num, i);
            pthread_exit(0);
        }
        sum1 += flo;
    }
    tcb->sum = sum1;
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    pthread_t tid1;
    pthread_t tid2;
    struct tcb tcb[2];
    pthread_attr_t attr;

    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    const char *filename = "input.txt";

    if ((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s for reading\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }
    tcb[0].fp = fp;
    tcb[0].thread_num = 0;
    tcb[0].sum = 0.0;
    tcb[1].fp = fp;
    tcb[1].thread_num = 1;
    tcb[1].sum = 0.0;
    pthread_create(&tid1, &attr, func1, &tcb[0]);
    pthread_create(&tid2, &attr, func1, &tcb[1]);
    pthread_join(tid1, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid2, NULL);
    printf("Total from thread 0 = %f\n", tcb[0].sum);
    printf("Total from thread 1 = %f\n", tcb[1].sum);
    printf("Grand total         = %f\n", tcb[0].sum + tcb[1].sum);
    return 0;
}
```

There are other ways to handle the input to and output from the thread function, but creating a simple structure seems quite simple and appropriate.

Given the data file (`input.txt`):

```
 23.192048
  4.128715
  3.465737
 74.307105
  4.329846
  6.098813
  9.497566
  6.988740
 11.530497
 53.262049
  9.469198
 41.305744
```

The output from one run was:

```
Total from thread 0 = 87.377665
Total from thread 1 = 109.423451
Grand total         = 196.801116
```

Other runs gave different values (one other run reversed the two results).  The two sums correspond to the lines 6-10 and 1-5 of the data file (which has 12 lines).  This shows that one thread manages to get scheduled and read its data quota, then leaving the other thread to read the next data quota.  Adding more threads (use loops and arrays of thread ID values) and more data might show different interleaved sequencing of the I/O operations.